# keep decrementing value on long press in Corona SDK

Tags: coronasdk

Hi i am working on a game and i have one object. On this object i have touch event. i have added a check on the touch even if the touch is less then 250ms consider it a tap otherwise consider it touch. On tap event i am incrementing a value by 10 point. i want to keep decrementing values by value of 1 as long as the object i being pressed, i have added the code but it is only doing it once.

The question is How do i keep decrementing a value as long as a touch event is recorded. the code is provided for reference below

```
local function countTaps(event)
 if event.phase == "began" then
beganTime = event.time
elseif event.phase == "ended" then
endedTime = event.time
if (endedTime - beganTime) < 250 then
  climbUp()
  return true
else
  climbDown()
end
end
```

However this code determine the tap/touch once it is finished. What can be the better runtime alternative

Answer (score 0):

When the touch event begins, set a timer to fire at the frequency you would like the value to change. When the timer fires, call a function that changes your counter (maybe your `climbDown()`).

When the touch ends, cancel the timer. You will want to make sure you detect the end of this touch even if it is no longer on your button.  You accomplish this by managing the focus on the stage as explained in [this guide](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/events/touchMultitouch/index.html).

For more information, consult the documentation for [`timer.*`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/index.html), specifically `timer.performWithDelay()` and `timer.cancel()`.

Comment: Also, information about [timer](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/performWithDelay.html), [timer.pause()](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/pause.html)  and [timer.resume()](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/resume.html) functions will be useful here.

Comment: it executes it only once when i add them as stated.

Comment: There is an optional iterations argument to `performWithDelay()` that makes it fire repeatedly if you specify a value of 0 or -1.  From the documentation: `timer.performWithDelay( delay, listener [, iterations] )`.  For example, to call `climbDown` every 200 ms (approximately), you would use `timer.performWithDelay( 200, climb down, -1 )`.

Comment: Beyond that, you'll have to update your question with the new code you're trying.  Otherwise, there isn't enough information to know why it isn't working.